# How to integrate GMail into an iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, email, gmail

I have followed this [tutorial](http://vimeo.com/22841414) to create an SMS view and I was wondering how I can automatically get emails every five seconds from this specific Google Mail account, when this view is active?
I would then like to be able to send an email using the "Send" button and the email body would be retrieved from the UITextField. You would also be able to specify your Google Mail account login details in two UITextFields (for Username & Password).

How can I do this? What's the best way of doing it